# css - Image not going next to text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I may be just tired and not paying attention, but I can't seem to get this icon next to the text that says "failed to load game". I tried all the solutions the internet has, to no avail. I highlighted the div in green for your convenience. Output: [polarisiframestyling.forstaken.repl.co](https://polarisiframestyling.forstaken.repl.co)

Code:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>funnies</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/204c1cf7c6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe id="game-frame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="75%" height="80%" cellspacing="0" src="https://example.com"></iframe>
   <div id="game-options">
   <div class="game-name-icon">
   <b><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x20?text=img" id="game-icon-sm" width="20" height="20"><p class="logo-options" id="logo-options">Failed to load game</p></b>
    </div>
   <div class="icons-options">
   <p><a href="#" style="padding-right: 10px;">
   <i class="fa-solid fa-heart" style="color: #ffffff;"></i></a>
   <a href="#">
   <i class="fa-solid fa-expand" style="color: #ffffff;" onclick="fullscreen()"></i></a>
   </p>
   </div>
   </div>
  <script src="fullscreen.js"></script>
  <script src="setdata.js"></script>
  <script>
  const myClass = document.querySelector('.fa-heart');

function favorite() {
  if (myClass.style.color === 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' || myClass.style.color === '') {
    myClass.style.color = '#c72e47';
  } else {
    myClass.style.color = '#ffffff';
  }
}

myClass.addEventListener('click', favorite);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Arial;
}
p{
  margin: 0;
}
#game-frame{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  border-top: 6px solid black;
  border-left: 6px solid black;
  border-right: 6px solid black;
  border-radius: 13px 13px 0px 0px;
}
#game-options{
  max-width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 6px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 13px 13px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
}
#game-options > b {
  display: inline-block;
}
.icons-options{
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
.game-name-icon{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the text is in a paragraph (`<p>`) that has default display of 'block', meaning that, by default, that text will go below whatever is before it. One way to keep the image on the same line is to add `display:inline-block;` as the css style of that paragraph. Another way is to put the image within that paragraph.

Comment: Good answer @Arlon. Putting the image in the paragraph is the way to go. Then, and ONLY then, is it ok to use the float property on the image. Or anywhere for that matter :)